# g++ 5.2 -Wuninitialized warning when calling template parameter pack with integer literal

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, clang++

After seeing [this Meeting C++ 2015 lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxKkUZYpPe0), I experimented with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Fun, typename... Param>
auto generic_bind(Fun fun, Param&&... param)
{
    return [fun, &param...] (auto&&... x)
    {
        return fun(std::forward<Param>(param)... , 
                   std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);
    };  
}

int demo(int a, int b, int c) { return a * b + c; }

int main()
{
    // does work with int variables
    int a = 11, b = 22, c = 33;
    auto f1 = generic_bind(demo, a); 
    auto f2 = generic_bind(f1, b);
    std::cout << f1(b, c) << f2(33); // both result in 275
}
```

When changing `main()` body to

```
     // does not work with int literals in g++ 5.2.0
     auto f1 = generic_bind(demo, 11); 
     auto f2 = generic_bind(f1, 22);
     std::cout << f1(22, 33) << f2(33);
```

with `clang++ -Wall` both worked correct, but GNU g++ 5.2 creates a -Wuninitialized warning:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:42: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
int demo(int a, int b, int c) { return a * b + c; }
                                         ^
main.cpp:27:31: note: '<anonymous>' was declared here
  auto f2 = generic_bind(f1, 22);
                               ^
main.cpp:14:42: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
int demo(int a, int b, int c) { return a * b + c; }
                                         ^
main.cpp:26:36: note: '<anonymous>' was declared here
     auto f1 = generic_bind(demo, 11);
```

and gives unexpected result 33 (see: [Coliru live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/653123c7835488cc)). Which compiler is correct on C++14?

Comment: `generic_bind` takes references to its arguments, which are temporaries created in the call to generic_bind and they go out of scope, so GCC seems to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behaviour, so anything can happen, and so arguably both compilers are correct! GCC's warnings are a helpful clue there is a problem, even if they don't explain the exact problem.

When you use integer literals it causes temporary `int` objects to be created and the `Params&&` reference parameters bind to those temporary rvalues. Your lambda then uses reference captures, so the closure that you return contains references to the temporaries.

Those temporaries go out of scope at the end of the full expression, i.e. at the semi-colon after the call to `generic_bind`. That means that when you invoke `f1` and `f2` you read from dangling references, which is undefined behaviour.

In the original code the `Params&&` parameters bind to the automatic variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, and then the closures contain references to those same objects, and they are still in scope when you invoke `f1` and `f2`. So the original code is OK (although if `f1` and `f2` escaped to a wider scope and outlived `a`, `b`, and `c` you would have the same problem).